# Use of function pointers for callling functions in a DLL

Tags: c++

Is it possible to call a function in a DLL loaded dynamically without making use of function pointers.

Comment: Technically, it isn't possible to call *any* function without a function pointer, as that is what a function's name is.

Comment: what is wrong with function pointer?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. this was an interview quesiton

Comment: @Amardeep: Absolutely not true. Function name is not a pointer. It can be (and often is) implicitly converted to a pointer by the standard function-to-pointer conversion. But in C++ when you call a function this conversion is *NOT applied*. In other words, it is possible to call a function without using a pointer in C++. What you said in your comment would be true for C language, where the function-to-pointer conversion is applied during the call, but not for C++.

Comment: @AndreyT: Ultimately all abstractions for the identity of a function (unmangled C name, overloaded C++ name, virtual function table offset, etc.) resolve in the object code down to a function pointer so the CPU can transfer to that address.  With respect to my statement above -- it lacks precision but I'd say 'absolutely not true' would be difficult to defend in court.  ;-)

Comment: @Amardeep: Well, that logic would apply to variables as well, which also resolve to a "pointer" in object code. So what you are basically trying to say that everything in memory "is a pointer". Every variable is a pointer, every function is a pointer. That might hold true within some specific terminology, but that is not true in C/C++ terminology. In C++ terminology it is incorrect to say that every variable is a pointer, or that every function is a pointer. What you are trying to describe actually has a completely different name in C++ terminology: it is called *lvalue*, not *pointer*.

Comment: @Amardeep: Note, BTW, that in C++ language functions are *lvalues*.

Comment: @AndreyT:  It appears the spirit of the comment was contraindicative to your view of system architecture.  No desire here to argue semantics.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sort of, depending on what you're trying to accomplish. At least for some purposes, the linker's `delayload` switch can give roughly the effect of explicit dynamic linking, without requiring that you define pointers to all the functions you're going to use, use `GetProcAddress` to assign values to those pointers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Delay Loaded DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) would be considered dynamic loading? If so, you call a function in it just like you would call a statically linked function.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will always need function pointers.

But why don't you make a wrapping class, with one method for every function in the DLL that you want to call, and handle the function-pointer stuff in the class.  That way you hide the function-pointer stuff for the rest of your application.